# How do I use a map to make cards sit next to each other and wrap with flexbox? They are just stacked on top of eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to have this pizza orders side by side and wrapping using flexbox. The cards are currently just stacking on top of each other on the left side of the page. Here is my current CSS and Code...

CSS

```
.cards {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .card {
    flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 1em);
}

p.left {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Javascript/HTML

```
render() {
        return(
        <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}></button>
                <h1>orders are:</h1>
                {this.state.orders.map((order) => (
            <div class="centered">
 
                    <section class="cards">
                         
                    <article class="card">
                    <p class="left">                  
                        <p>Crust: {order.Crust}</p>
                        <p>Flavor: {order.Flavor}</p>
                        <p>Size: {order.Size}</p>
                        <p>Table Number: {order.Table_No}</p>
                    </p>
                    </article>
         
            </section>
        </div>

                ))}
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one card in the code so it will only display the single card. When I added several copies of the below code, it appeared with 4 cards side by side.

```
<article class="card">
                <p class="left">                  
                    <p>Crust: {order.Crust}</p>
                    <p>Flavor: {order.Flavor}</p>
                    <p>Size: {order.Size}</p>
                    <p>Table Number: {order.Table_No}</p>
                </p>
                </article>
```

Comment: But then the map does not work as intended. Since each card would have all every order instead of each order.

Comment: Are you wanting a single map and then the orders to appear in cards underneath?